# How to Run a other codes based on the value of a variable, wait a few minutes, check the variable and run again?

Tags: c#

I am getting the row count from a database and assigning it to a variable.
I need to run or call other `Classes` and `Methods` from the `Main Method` of a `Console App` based on the value assigned to the variable from the database.

Here are the steps:

1. Check the variable, if it is greater than zero
2. Run the code in side the main method conditional statement
3. **The wait** for X seconds
4. Check the variable again and if it is still greater than zero, run and wait again.
5. Finally, if the variable is equals zero, exit the console.

What I do not know is how to repeat the wait and execute.

The following code i an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int intCheckRowCount = Database.DataExists();

    while (intCheckRowCount > 0)
    {
        //Run code in here
        Thread.Sleep(20000);
        //Run Code again
    }

    //Exit when variable is zero
}
```

Comment: Well you've already got the "repeat and wait" - you just need to execute `intCheckRowCount = Database.DataExists()` in the loop as well, and call whatever methods you need. You might also want to consider using a `Timer`.

Comment: for delay in code you can use system.threading.thread.sleep(time in miliseconds);

Answer (score -1):

**Problem :** if you want to wait for some amount of time you need to use `Timer` instead of calling `Thread.Sleep()` function. because `Thread.Sleep()` will Stop/hang the Main thread and your application becomes unresponsive for given amount of time.

**Solution :** you can use `System.Timers.Timer` as shown below

Try This:

```
    class Program
    {
        static  System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        int intCheckRowCount =0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 20000;//20 seconds
            timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Start();                
        }
        static private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            intCheckRowCount = Database.DataExists();
            if(intCheckRowCount ==0)
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, so where am I calling the code so that it works with the timer interval?

Comment: Hello, is there a way to make code run immediately and then have the timer kick in on subsequent evaluation?

Comment: This will not work at all, your program exits immediately after you call `timer1.Start()`, now if this was a GUI application instead of a console application your approach would be correct but this is wrong for a console application.

Comment: Scott: Do you have a suggestion or a solution?